# Conditional subtraction in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, conditional-statements

I have a fairly straightforward need, but I can't find a previously asked question that is similar enough. I've been trying with dplyr, but can't figure it out.

```
 julian year
   088   22
   049   19
   041   22
   105   18
   125   22
   245   20
```

What I want is for each value where data$julian < 105, subtract '1' from data$year, so that

```
 julian year
   088   21
   049   18
   041   21
   105   18
   125   22
   245   20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP asked about using `dplyr` in the post.  Here, is one with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(year = case_when(as.numeric(julian) < 105 ~ year -1,
     TRUE ~ as.numeric(year)))
```

-output

```
df1
 julian year
1    088   21
2    049   18
3    041   21
4    105   18
5    125   22
6    245   20
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(julian = c("088", "049", "041", "105", "125", 
"245"), year = c(22L, 19L, 22L, 18L, 22L, 20L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Works great, thank you!
Just for my own sake, could you elaborate on the underlying rationale? 
I understand everything except for the latter part, TRUE ~ year ?

Comment: @Treebeard `TRUE~` is kind of default option.  If we didn't specify, all other cases will return `NA`, by `TRUE ~ as.numeric(year)`, specifying the values of 'year' to return. `case_when` is very specific about returning the same type, `year -1` returns numeric type, thus I wrapped `as.numeric` which is otherwise `integer`

Answer (score 1):

Another option with base R:

```
df$year[df$julian < 105] <- df$year[df$julian < 105] - 1
```

**Output**

```
  julian year
1    088   21
2    049   18
3    041   21
4    105   18
5    125   22
6    245   20
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("KKSWAP", "KKSWAP"), code = c("The liquidations code for Marco are: 51-BMR05, 74-VAD08, 176-VNF09.", 
"The liquidations code for Clara are: 88-BMR05, 90-VAD08, 152-VNF09."
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```